# Use wildcard for graph API Microsoft with $filter

Tags: email, filter, microsoft-graph-api, wildcard

During a Microsoft graph API call, I'm looking to retrieve an email from its subject with the following python code:
`f"$filter=subject eq '{subject}'"`

The problem is that the filter separator <<'>> is present in the subject, the variable <<subject>>.

So I'm looking to replace the <<'>> with wildcard to keep the current method.

I tried replacing the <<'>> with <<">>, but the filter doesn't work with them, it absolutely needs <<'>>.

Comment: could you please share the code how do you replace `'` with `''`?

Comment: @user2250152    code with <<">> ==>  f"$filter=subject eq \"{subject}\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to duplicate a single quote `'` which is present in the subject

```
subject = subject.replace("'","''")
f"$filter=subject eq '{subject}'"
```

It will ensure that a single quote is [escaped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#escaping-single-quotes)

Comment: Hello

I have implemented this solution, thank you for your help.